# Query to 'get the records from the actual month' doesn't get me the records that have a bigger day that the current one

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date, sql-date-functions

I have the following query to get the records from a table from the current month

```
select *
from 
   myTable 
where 
   my_date BETWEEN trunc (sysdate, 'mm') AND SYSDATE;
```

This query works if the records have a lower day compared to the current one 
example: if today is `27/10/2016` and I have a record that have this date: `28/10/2016` 
The record with date `28/10/2016` is not showing

I insert the records using this format `TO_DATE( '28/10/2016 18:02:44', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')`

I want to show all the records from the curren month even if the day is bigger than the actual date

Comment: Do you need all the dates >= than the first day of the current month?

Comment: I just want the records that have a date in the current month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either:

```
select *
from 
   myTable 
where 
   my_date BETWEEN trunc (sysdate, 'mm') AND add_months(trunc (sysdate, 'mm'),1)- 1/(24*3600)
```

or

```
select *
from 
   myTable 
where 
   trunc(my_date,'mm') = trunc (sysdate, 'mm')
```

The first is sargable, the second is more readable.

Comment: thanks I tried the second one and it worked, but I don't know if I should accept the answer since the question was down voted and that would be against stackoverflow policies, Should I delete my question instead??

Comment: Just a note on the first solution proposed - if you have time elements in your my_date column, then you will be missing all rows that are after midnight on the last day. `my_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm') and my_date < add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), 1)` would be one way to get around that problem. And as for the second solution - if you have an index on the my_date column, that query will no longer be able to use it. Instead, you'd need to create a separate function-based-index (fbi) to create an index on `trunc(my_date, 'mm')`.

Comment: @JohnHC thanks for teaching me a new word, btw! I've never come across "sargable" before!

Answer (score 1):

If you need the dates in the current month

```
trunc(my_date, 'mm') = trunc(sysdate, 'mm')
```

If you need the dates from the current month and on:

```
my_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm')
```

Comment: If there are no dates in future months, this would work